# Terminal command slower in verbose mode for huge files?

Tags: mysql, terminal, verbose

I have to restore a few MySQL schemes that are sometimes 400GB.
Since I want to know what's going on I'm a fan of verbose mode in terminal commands. 
But I'm wondering if there are disadvantages for such big files when they have to be display in terminal window?

Answer (score 1):

Displaying progress is always going to be a strain on the Terminal, imagine if I was writing a article, and you asked me to give you a progress update you every time I finished a sentence, rather than letting me do my own thing, and simply tell you once I'm done, or if I have any problems and cannot proceed.

I don't know exactly what command you're running but if it's 400GB of SQL related files, you can imagine what it would print in Terminal.

If you want to test this for yourself, try running smaller files in both verbose and non-verbose mode with timers and see the difference.

I don't think the overall command would be amazingly slower with verbose mode on, however, there's a strain nonetheless.